# How to control the scaling with the Color Ramp node so that the scaling is smooth?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

I need to control the scaling of the mesh with a color ramp so that the effect is smooth like the mesh on the right. I tried different combinations of the nodes in the picture, but nothing worked for me.
[image]

Comment: The mesh on the right is smooth only in middle, not on the start and end of the gradient. Have you tried switching "Linear" mode to other options?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady It does not have to be exactly the same as on the gradient. The main requirement is that it should be guided by a gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Scale Elements* will separate the *Selection*, and then separate that by mesh islands, and then scale the islands. So if you don't want the cuboid to be simply scaled as a single object, you need to separate the horizontal edges. Then you need to simply pass the $z$ coordinate to the *Color Ramp*, but since the ramp expects inputs in range $[0,1]$, all $z$ coordinates below $0$ will read as $0$, and all $z$ coordinates above $1$ will read as $1$ (they will be *clamped* to the expected range). To combat this I use an *Attribute Statistic* node, but you could as well e.g. just divide the coordinate by the height of the mesh if it started at zero as in your case… Notice the "Ease" mode…

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But explain to me please, what does node "Not Equal" do?

Comment: @arachnoden vertical edges are at an angle of $90°$ to a horizontal vector, so I select edges that aren't at that angle. The Vector $<1, 1, 0>$ was picked, but any vector with $z = 0$ would do as long as both $x$ and $y$ weren't equal (or very close to, due to εpsilon allowing some fuzziness) to $0$ (because an edge parallel to $y$ axis is at $90°$ to $<1, 0, 0>$ and an edge parallel to $x$ axis is at $90°$ to $<0, 1, 0>$, and we want to select those horizontal edges).